# QtIFW Always create registry entry

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm currently using the Qt-Installer-Framework to create a setup for my application. Everything works fine for now except one thing:

If I install it to any location but `C:\Program Files\MyApp`, the installer won't create the registry entry for `Programs and Features`!

Is there a way to tell the installer to always do this?

**Edit:**
After trying out vairous different combinations, I do know now where the problem comes from:

If I try to install as current user only (set the `AllUsers` variable to `false`), it will always work and create an entry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID}`.

If I install for all users, however, it will try to create a key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{GUID}`. This will only work, if the installer has to elevate it's operations during installation (because I chose a directory I need admin rights for).

So, the error is: The installer won't elevate itself to create the "global" registry entry and thus fails to create it. Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: It's a Windows 10 machine

Comment: How do you switch between `AllUsers` `true` and`false`? I can't find anything regarding this option in the docs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510656/how-to-distinguish-per-user-vs-system-wide-installation-in-qt-installer-framewo

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning I just checked and it is an extension, used by an advanced controller script. See https://github.com/Skycoder42/QtIFW-Advanced-Setup/blob/master/installer/config/controller.js

Comment: Thanks, the important thing is to set the value earlier than I did using `installer.setValue`. Besides that, one can provide that on the shell as well: `installer.exe AllUsers=true` https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-124

Answer (score 2):

Here the [link](https://forum.qt.io/topic/35272/qt-installer-framework-and-administrator-privileges-solved/2) which has answer to this question.

> Add the following line to your component's package xml file:
>
> @<RequiresAdminRights>true</RequiresAdminRights>@
>
> And use this line in your script file:
>
> @component.addElevatedOperation("Execute", "someCommand");@
>
> instead of
>
> @component.addOperation("Execute", "someCommand");@

Comment: I know this one. However, I don't want to always run as admin, only elevate if the setup is being installed for all users (decided at runtime with a custom page). Furthermore, I did not create any operation to add the registry entry. This is done automatically by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

There is `boolean installer.gainAdminRights()` to gain elevated privileges during runtime but you will have to add it to an installer script (in packages meta directory) something alike

```
function Component()
{
    if (!installer.isInstaller())
    {
        if (allUsers && installer.gainAdminRights())
        {
            //Set registry global
        } else {
            //Set registry local
        }
    }
}
```